# C# Minor Issue when Iterating through file

Tags: c#

I have a program that iterates through all files from directories and subdirectories, it's working smoothly but there is just a minor issue that my brain can't solve.
The one finding the simplest way to solve it is a genius :)

Here is the code :

```
    int hello(string locat)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(locat);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(locat);
        int cpt = 0;
        
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(file+"\r\n");

                cpt++;
                textBox2.AppendText(cpt.ToString()+"\r\n");
            }
            catch { }
        }

        
        foreach (string directory in dirs)
        {
            try
            {
                cpt += hello(directory);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        return cpt;

    }
```

So the problem is that the output of cpt inside textBox2 have a logic behavior but a behavior that is not adequate for my needs

This is how it looks like :

```
1
2
3
1
2
1
2
...
```

And I want it to be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...

I tried with EnumerateFiles instead of GetFiles, it was working smoothly too but i got some permissions issue and I'm working on .NET framework for this project

Comment: Is solvable,  however the underlying problem is that you are doing to many things at once. You should first collect all file names,  iteratively or not. In a second step you can add them to a text box, using the index of list. Or possible use an IEnumerable and the special overload of Linqs Select, giving an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variation that avoids `ref`

```
int hello(string locat, int counter = 0)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(locat);
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(locat);
        

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        try
        {
            textBox2.AppendText(file + "\r\n");

            counter++;
            textBox2.AppendText(counter.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }
        catch { }
    }


    foreach (string directory in dirs)
    {
        try
        {
            counter = hello(directory, counter);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    return counter;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what if I want to add a new counter for the file size just under counter++ like size += file.Length; can I also do it without the ref ?

Comment: ref works.
You can return the sum of length. If you want a count too, you can either do an out param, ref param, or return a tuple or object with all the properties you care about.

Also, you could return all of the file info as a list and use Linq and/or treat it as a flat list as opposed to recursive. You can use the ref approach or return and append the child list.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this but you can just make `hello` take `cpt` as a parameter.

```
    int hello(string locat, ref int cpt)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(locat);
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(locat);
        
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(file+"\r\n");

                cpt++;
                textBox2.AppendText(cpt.ToString()+"\r\n");
            }
            catch { }
        }

        
        foreach (string directory in dirs)
        {
            try
            {
                hello(directory, ref cpt);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        return cpt;

    }
```

Edit:

You need to run it with `ref`

```
int cpt = 0;
hello("C:\\", ref cpt);
```

Here is the output I get if I run it with the following folder structure:

```
testfolder/
 > folder1/
  > a.txt
  > b.txt
  > c.txt
 > folder2/
  > a.txt
  > b.txt
  > c.txt
 > folder3/
  > a.txt
  > b.txt
  > c.txt
```

Output:

```
D:\testfolder\folder1\a.txt
1
D:\testfolder\folder1\b.txt
2
D:\testfolder\folder1\c.txt
3
D:\testfolder\folder2\a.txt
4
D:\testfolder\folder2\b.txt
5
D:\testfolder\folder2\c.txt
6
D:\testfolder\folder3\a.txt
7
D:\testfolder\folder3\b.txt
8
D:\testfolder\folder3\c.txt
9
```

Comment: I already tried it of course and it's not working, the behavior is very very strange you can try it you will see big numbers it look like exponential

Comment: @RenardoSharp unfortunately I cannot try it, I do not have your setup and I am writing this on a environment without c#.

Comment: your answer is very logic and that is what I tried the first time I ran into this issue but apparently it's not working as expected, thanks anyways Abé :)

Comment: @RenardoSharp I just tried it and it works. Please check the edit

Comment: No, it doesn't work. You use a ref parameter (`ref int cpt`) that you increment. So far so good. But then you also do `cpt += hello(directory, cpt);`, which is nonsensical, as with respect to cpt it is equivalent to `cpt += cpt`.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Wait I'll do a test in a proper folder and get back to you

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace excatly what I though, it's not working because it adds the file number to cpt so it will be exponential

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace fixed it, just remove ```cpt +=```. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Alright. Looks good. One could debate whether the method should return the value of cpt or not (strictly not necessary, since cpt is a ref parameter), but that would be a debate that at best would only be tangentially related to the question...

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys, much love :)

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `cpt` is locally scoped, so you get a new variable instance for every recursive call. You can instead use a field (and don't increment it based on the result of your recursive call):

```
int cpt = 0;
void hello(string locat)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(locat);
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(locat);


    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        try
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(file + "\r\n");

            cpt++;
            textBox2.AppendText(cpt.ToString() + "\r\n");
        }
        catch { }
    }


    foreach (string directory in dirs)
    {
        try
        {
            hello(directory);
        }
        catch { }
    }

}
```

This code is not thread-safe.